# automating the navigation between pages of a website with VBA

Tags: html, ms-access, web, dom, vba

I'm landing on a webpage that has a menu on the left looking like this

```
Client
    contact history list inquiry
    contact history list
Client Search
Client Service
```

when you click on an item (eg: client) the sub items appear.  if you click on a sub item, it brings you to a new page.

I am trying to automate these 2 steps using VBA.  but I'm having no luck.  Here is the related html

Collapsed

```
<P tabIndex=0 class=inactiveMenuItem _submenuid="menuLevel10"  _ingeniummenuid="00100">Client</P>
<UL id=menuLevel10 class=hiddenMenu _ingeniummenuid="00100" _parentmenuid="menuLevel1"></UL></LI>
```

Expanded

```
<P tabIndex=0 class=inactiveMenuItem _submenuid="menuLevel10" _ingeniummenuid="00100">Client</P>
<UL id=menuLevel10 class=visibleMenu _ingeniummenuid="00100" _parentmenuid="menuLevel1" _populated="true">
<LI><A class=inactiveMenuItem href="#" _flowname="BF1325InqList">Contact History List Inquiry</A></LI>
<LI><A class=inactiveMenuItem href="#" _flowname="BF1324List">Contact History List</A></LI>
```

I tried something like this

```
Dim objIE As New InternetExplorerMedium
Dim objDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim objElement As IHTMLElement

'go to website
objIE.Navigate ("http://SOMESITE.COM") (not the real site)
objIE.Visible = True

'sleep half seconds until page is loaded
Do Until objIE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Sleep (500)
Loop

'click on menu item
Set objDoc = objIE.Document
Set objElement = objDoc.getElementById("menuLevel10")
objElement.Click
```

which didn't work.  I also tried to trigger the OnClick event with the FireEvent function but that did not work either.  Any help is appreciated.  My knowledge of HTML is very limited so please tell me if I should add more of the HTML source code or if pieces of information are missing.

EDIT: it's an intranet site if that changes anything

Comment: You should try to add an example of the website. If your website is on intranet, you can create a basic test example just for us.

Comment: @TomasZubiri do you mean like a screenshot of the website?

Comment: Or the html code of the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.  basically, the element that I needed to click is not referenced by an ID, so I have to loop through all elements until I find the one I need (I used the innerHTML property to get a match).  once I have the element object, I can click it and it does what it is supposed to do.  I will add a code example when I have time

Something like this

```
Do Until objdoc.body.all(lngIdx).innerHTML = "Client"
    lngIdx = lngIdx + 1
    If lngIdx = objdoc.body.all.Length Then
        MsgBox "Could not find Menu Item"
        Exit Function
    End If
Loop
objdoc.body.all(lngIdx).Click
```

and then the same thing for the sub menu

```
Do Until objdoc.body.all(lngIdx).innerHTML = "Contact History List Inquiry"
    lngIdx = lngIdx + 1
    If lngIdx = objdoc.body.all.Length Then
        MsgBox "Could not find Sub Menu Item"
        Exit Function
    End If
Loop
objdoc.body.all(lngIdx).Click
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with Selenium for VBA (https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic)

After installing Selenium in your computer and including it in Excel's references.

The code to navigate such a website would be:

```
Dim Browser As New Selenium.IEDriver
Browser.get "http://SOMESITE.COM"

browser.wait 5000

browser.findElementById("menuLevel10").click
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don't think this is a viable option.  what I'm building will be rolled out to other users and I assume they would need to download Selenium too